# HP Pavillion 17-e67cl Black screen Ubuntu 14.04, only boots with vga in

Tags: 14.04, screen

During the boot up of the livecd of ubuntu, the screen was black.

I connected the computer to VGA to see what was happening. Once ubuntu started up (I used the try ubuntu option) I could then see everything so I disconnected the VGA.

I installed it fine. I then turn on the computer to find that it stays at a black screen and from the fans and lack of login sound, I know that it is stuck at some startup process. (I had it set to log in automatically) I try again with the vga attached and it went in perfectly to the desktop and the desktop showed on the laptop screen again.

I tried setting the Grub to `nosetmode` and have had no luck researching this problem. The black screen is on grub, the loading screen, and the login screen. (The lock screen and login screen work fine if you log out or lock computer, only a problem when just turning computer on)

The 2 issues:

- Needs VGA to load ubuntu
- Screen shows black during everything before login.

Computer: HP Pavillion 17-e67cl
Ubuntu: 14.04-LTS

This is getting marked as a duplicate when in fact it is not a duplicate, please read fully through a question before setting it to duplicate moderators. I already had a reply claiming it was a duplicate and I explained that nomodeset did not work. The solution in the other thread does not work, I need a new solution. I did however get another reply which I will be testing soon. I also wrote that there are 2 issues, UBUNTU will not start up unless vga is plugged in, I can tell this by the fans. When i tried recovery mode and did failsafe graphics it had an error code. No Monitor Attatched. This is a laptop therefore there is clearly a monitor attatched. The computer does not read the laptop monitor as being attatched until I am logged in.

Comment: "I tried setting the grub to nosetmode" All that says to do is set nosetmode on. My computer is still not working after that. I can not get to even the first purple screen on the cd unless another monitor is attatched. After installing I modified the grub and set nomodeset and still have these problems.

Comment: There are quite a lot of other answers there besides using `nomodeset` (*not* `sosetmode`). Did you try any of those? Anyhow, your question isn't that clear. What do you see if you start the machine with no VGA, then plug it in a few minutes later? What graphics card do you have? Did you try the answer below? What was the error code?

Answer (score 0):

I have a HP Pavilion DV5 and I always needed to use <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to increase brightness.

To correct this issue I needed add the `acpi_backlight=vendor` in Grub.

---

Open the grub file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Locate this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

and add the option `acpi_backlight=vendor`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Save and close the file

Update the Grub with this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then, restart your system.